# Python: Check if string is a number WITHOUT using regex or try-except

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

First post here, tried searching but everybody's answers are 'use regex'..hope I conform well enough to the other standards of the site.

Just learning python and a hw assignment was to create a function to test if a string is a number.  Easy enough using exceptions.  We were asked to come up with another way of testing and the hint was to use regular expressions.  Again, easy enough.

In my own attempt to get a better feel for python, I wanted to do the same thing WITHOUT regex and wanted the added functionality of any string that could evaluate to a number to return True, so for example, '5++-3j + + 4.j-6.1' should return True, but 'j32' would return False.

I'm running into some problems: for example, '5j' is False but '+5j' and '+=5j' are both True.  Also, the print statements in the function are just so I can see what the computer sees at various stages. Thanks!

Edit: I realize the unfortunate placement of variable j with complex number j, but the quotes should make clear to which j is being referred.

Edit: as noted by @georg, I am looking to test if a string is a numeric expression, if it evaluates to a number

```
def is_itnumber(el):
    '''Identifies if a string can be converted to a number, in an unuseful way!'''
    mast=[]
    el_p=el.split(sep='+')
    for el_m in el_p:
        n=el_m.split(sep='-')
        mast.extend(n)
    for l in mast:
        if l=='': mast.remove(l)
        print(mast)
        for j in range(len(l)):
            print( l[j])
            if l[j]==',':
                if j not in range(len(l)-3):
                    return False
                elif (l[j+1].isdigit()==0 or l[j+2].isdigit()==0 or l[j+3].isdigit()==0):
                    return False
            elif l[j]=='j':
                if j != len(l):
                    return False
            elif l[j]=='.':
                for x in range(len(l)):
                    if l[x]=='.' and x!=j:
                        return False
            elif l[j].isdigit()==0:
                    return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: What the heck kind of number is `5++-3j + + 4.j-6.1` ????????

Comment: I'm failing to see how `5j' or any other thing in your post is a number. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Adam Smith, want '5++-3j + + 4.j-6.1' to return True since '5++-3j + + 4.j-6.1'='-1.1+1j' as a complex number.

Comment: @s16h complex numbers should be included, I'm looking for full generality.

Comment: @AdamSmith try putting `4.j` into an interpreter.

Comment: @user3654190 You can't do this in a regular way.  `+5j` is legal but `5j+` is a `SyntaxError`.  You'll need to actually parse the expression with, say, shunting-yard.

Comment: @roippi I see! That's...odd....

Comment: @AdamSmith, looking to create a function that returns True as much as possible while allowing for poorly formed strings.  The idea behind your gripe is to say a number plus 'whitespace' is number plus zero, similarly, 4.j is the same as 4j or 4.0j (FYI--in python complex('4.j') returns 4j)

Comment: @user3654190 the lazy way to do this is just `eval` but it carries with it all the usual security concerns.

Comment: Do people here really not understand complex numbers?

Comment: @roippi, isn't splitting the string using '+' and '-' as delimiters avoiding those SyntaxError's?

Comment: @user3654190 well I'm not sure what you *want* it to be.  Putting `5j+` into a python interpreter gives a `SyntaxError` - is that your desired output?  Or...?

Comment: @roippi, '4+32j+5'.split('+')=['4', '32j', '5']  then the function goes into the list and looks at each element (after splitting over any minus signs as well).  I guess I'm not sure why there would be any SyntaxError's since the function begins by breaking the string down into the alpanumeric parts.

Comment: My point is that your algorithm needs to be defined over invalid inputs (like `5j+`) as well as valid inputs.  You seem to be concerned with one *class* of invalid inputs (the numbers being malformed) while ignoring another class of invalid inputs (the operators being unbalanced).

Comment: @roippi, I see, thanks for clarifying, I still think the function avoids that though.. '5j+'.split(sep='+')=[5j], while I haven't addressed any operators beyond addition/subtraction, splitting the string over said operators creates a list devoid of any '+' and '-', the elements of the list will never be of the form '5j+'

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what `5++-3j + + 4.j-6.1` is. But if you wanted to test for integers in string `s`:

```
all(['0' <= c <= '9' for c in s])
```

You can expand for floats:

```
all(['0' <= c <= '9' for c in s]) and s.count('.') <= 1
```

Beyond this, you are basically implementing a custom regex engine that is likely to be buggy and perform poorly.

EDIT: I stand corrected:

```
>>> 5++-3j + + 4.j-6.1 
(-1.0999999999999996+1j)
```

The only other idea I have would be to use `ast.parse`.

Comment: thanks for the edit, I'll check ast.parse out, I have no idea what it is at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean "a numeric expression" rather than just a "number" in your question. `5++-3j + + 4.j-6.1` is definitely not a number, but it's a valid "numeric expression". Since this is a language, you need a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages) to validate it. Fortunately, python provides a way to parse itself: the [ast module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html). Without claiming completeness, here's a sketch of a possible implementation:

```
import ast

class CheckNumeric(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def validate(self, expr):
        self.valid = True
        self.visit(ast.parse(expr))
        return self.valid

    def check(self, node):
        operators = [ast.Add, ast.Sub, ast.Mult, ast.Div, ast.UAdd, ast.USub]
        if type(node) in [ast.BinOp, ast.UnaryOp]:
            return type(node.op) in operators
        return type(node) in operators + [ast.Module, ast.Expr, ast.Num]

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        if not self.check(node):
            self.valid = False
        if self.valid:
            ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)
```

This class should accept numeric expressions and reject all others:

```
print CheckNumeric().validate('5++-3j + + 4.j-6.1') # True
print CheckNumeric().validate('j32') # False
print CheckNumeric().validate('foo((((') # SyntaxError
```

Comment: I revised the post to indicate numeric expression, thanks!  At the moment, this implementation is over my head; I don't understand the 'self' argument although I see it often in Python code.  I think we are learning about classes soon, hopefully your solution will make more sense to me in short order.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @Ben, a function with a small tweak to handle floats correctly.

```
def is_string_numeric(s):
    # Test if string represents an integer or float

    # remove all decimal points before checking digits
    s2 = s.replace('.','')  
    # Check for digits in s2 and no more than one decimal place in s
    return all(['0' <= c <= '9' for c in s2]) and s.count('.') <= 1

# test cases
print(is_string_numeric('68768.1'))        # True
print(is_string_numeric('123.345.1'))      # False
print(is_string_numeric('7641746183746'))  # True
print(is_string_numeric('D7641746183746')) # False
```